# carthage update is not working

Tags: swift, woocommerce, carthage

I'm trying to use woocommerce SDK for iOS and I have a cartfile

```
github "thii/WooCommerceSDK"
```

When I type 'carthage update' from my project directory, it gives me a error like

```
A shell task (/usr/bin/env git fetch --prune --quiet https://github.com/thii/WooCommerceSDK.git refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*) 
failed with exit code 128:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

I use git with https exclusively, going back and forth between my personal and work GitHub accounts, and it has been a pain until [I found how to set it up to save credentials on a per-repository basis](https://coderwall.com/p/9ub-6a/using-multiple-accounts-with-git-or-github#new-comment) (now it asks me user name and password once, when first cloning each repo, and never again).

When I tried adding a framework to my project using Carthage and get started by running:

```
$ carthage update
```

...I would get the error:

> A shell task (/usr/bin/env git clone --bare --quiet
>   https://github.com/ORGANIZATION_NAME/REPOSITORY_NAME.git
>   /Users/LOCAL_USER_NAME/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/FRAMEWORK_NAME)
>   failed with exit code 128: fatal: could not read Username for
>   'https://github.com/ORGANIZATION_NAME/REPOSITORY_NAME.git': **terminal
>   prompts disabled**

*(emphasis mine)*

The discussion for issue [#219](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/219) on the Carthage Github page gave the hint to clon e the repo once somewhere, just to have git store my credentials for that URL once, and then run `$ carthage update` once again in my project's directory, and it worked.

It's an ugly workaround, but I hope it helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because he changed his username to "minhcasi".
So you have to use

```
github "minhcasi/WooCommerceSDK"
```

instead of

```
github "thii/WooCommerceSDK"
```

Share the result with me!